# CocosSharp - Empty project debug error

Tags: xamarin, cocossharp

I try to run empty CocosSharp project in XamarinStudio (http://screencast.com/t/gW9acuyx7), but i get some errors.
References (http://screencast.com/t/yRgHcsUijgPk)
Can anyone give me advice on why it doesn't work anymore?

Comment: You are showing the references from the wrong project, what references have you included on your `Game.Common` project?

Comment: I have problem with adding references to this project http://screencast.com/t/xDdhxGjiQrAx What should i do now?

Comment: You are targeting the wrong profile in that project, read the last line of the output...